# Spark - How to use SparkContext within classes?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am building an application in Spark, and would like to use the SparkContext and/or SQLContext within methods in my classes, mostly to pull/generate data sets from files or SQL queries.

For example, I would like to create a T2P object which contains methods that gather data (and in this case need access to the SparkContext):

```
class T2P (mid: Int, sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext) extends Serializable {

  def getImps(): DataFrame = {
      val imps = sc.textFile("file.txt").map(line => line.split("\t")).map(d => Data(d(0).toInt, d(1), d(2), d(3))).toDF()
      return imps
   }

  def getX(): DataFrame = {
      val x = sqlContext.sql("SELECT a,b,c FROM table")
      return x
  }
}

//creating the T2P object
class App {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("T2P App").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val t2p = new T2P(0, sc, sqlContext);
}
```

Passing the SparkContext as an argument to the T2P class doesn't work since the SparkContext is not serializable (getting a `task not serializable` error when creating T2P objects).  What is the best way to use the  SparkContext/SQLContext inside my classes?  Or perhaps is this the wrong way to design a data pull type process in Spark?

***UPDATE***
Realized from the comments on this post that the SparkContext was not the problem, but that I was using a using a method within a 'map' function, causing Spark to try to serialize the entire class.  This would cause the error since SparkContext is not serializable.

```
def startMetricTo(userData: ((Int, String), List[(Int, String)]), startMetric: String) : T2PUser = {
  //do something 
}

def buildUserRollup() = {
  this.userRollup = this.userSorted.map(line=>startMetricTo(line, this.startMetric))
}
```

This results in a 'task not serializable' exception.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Can you provide examples? All your code runs on master node except for those parts which are in rdd transformation closures. On master node you don't need serialization. And in inside rdd transformation you don't need sparkContext. Can you clarify your aim?

Comment: updated.  does that help?

Comment: Well, why do you need serialization? Rethink it: all distributed work is done inside rdd transformations like `map\filter`. You just don't need serialization for your repository helper.

Comment: Well the motivation for this post is that I am getting a `task not serializable` error when creating a T2P object.

Comment: Could you show the place where you created it? It looks like you do it inside rdd transformation. In addition, can you replace `class` with `object`?

Comment: updated.  T2P should remain a class in this case.

Comment: I am using this same approach and it is working fine. Passing SparkContext and SqlContext as parameters should not generate this error on instantiation of the class (at least in 1.4).  There are a couple of things that I could see causing problems.  One is, if your class "Data" is not serializable for whatever reason, you could get that exception.  The other could be if you have methods that aren't listed in your example that are doing something more complicated (for example, closures can break the task serialization), that could also cause issues.

Comment: Can you share stacktrace when you get serialization error?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem (with the help of the commenters and other StackOverflow users) by creating a separate `MetricCalc` object to store my startMetricTo() method.   Then I changed the buildUserRollup() method to use this new startMetricTo(). This allows the entire `MetricCalc` object to be serialized without issue.

```
//newly created object
object MetricCalc {
    def startMetricTo(userData: ((Int, String), List[(Int, String)]), startMetric: String) : T2PUser = {
    //do something
  }
}

//using function in T2P
def buildUserRollup(startMetric: String) = {
   this.userRollup = this.userSorted.map(line=>MetricCalc.startMetricTo(line, startMetric))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several options, this is what worked eventually for me..

```
   object SomeName extends App {

   val conf = new SparkConf()...
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   implicit val sqlC = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
   getDF1(sqlC)

   def getDF1(sqlCo: SQLContext): Unit = {
    val query1 =  SomeQuery here  
    val df1 = sqlCo.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> dbUrl,"dbtable" -> query1)).load.cache()

     //iterate through df1 and retrieve the 2nd DataFrame based on some values in the Row of the first DataFrame

    df1.foreach(x => {
     getDF2(x.getString(0), x.getDecimal(1).toString, x.getDecimal(3).doubleValue) (sqlCo)
   })     
  }

  def getDF2(a: String, b: String, c: Double)(implicit sqlCont: SQLContext) :  Unit = {
     val query2 = Somequery

     val sqlcc = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
    //val sqlcc = sqlCont //Did not work for me. Also, omitting (implicit sqlCont: SQLContext) altogether did not work
     val df2 = sqlcc.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> dbURL, "dbtable" -> query2)).load().cache()
       .
       .
       .
     }
  }
```

Note: In the above code, if I omitted (implicit sqlCont: SQLContext) parameter from getDF2 method signature, it would not work. I tried several other options of passing the sqlContext from one method to the other, it always gave me NullPointerException or Task not serializable Excpetion. Good thins is it eventually worked this way, and I could retrieve parameters from a row of the DataFrame1 and use those values in loading the DataFrame 2.